# can't use @Entity annotation in spring boot, gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, gradle, spring-data-jpa

This is my `build.gradle` file dependencies,

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
   testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
      exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
   }
   implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
   compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
   compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-mail', version: '2.4.1'
   implementation group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'

}
```

I created model class for student. But I can't use `@Entity` annotation it marks as the compile error. How I create an Entity using gradle?

Comment: You have to include this in your `build.gradle`: `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'`

Suggest you use start.spring.io to generate spring boot project. Your gradle file looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

@Entity Annotation is imported from javax.persistence.*

Make sure you have the following

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.4.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

First time using gradle with Intellij
Did not download the gradle imports (probably pressed 'build' on wrong file).

You can also just download the .jar and add it manually to your IDE.
Gradle / Maven do this for you but if you are done debugging you can use this!